# Assigning vs initialising structure variables

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I'm initialising an array of structures in main(); I get an error, when I declare and assign them separately.

This is my code snippet from main();

```
struct item newitem[10];
newitem[0]={1,"pen",5,10};
struct item new2= {2,"ygh",9,0};
```

This is the error I get on line 2.
The line 3 works fine, however.

`[Error] expected expression before '{' token`

What could be the reason?

Comment: If the third line is supposed to initialize `newitem[1]` or `newitem[2]`, it fails to do so.  Why not include the initializer for `newitem[0]` in the definition of `newitem`, which has the additional merit of initializing (to zeros) all the other elements of the array of structures.  `struct item newitem[10] = { { 1, "pen", 5, 10, }, };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use compound literal:

```
newitem[0] = (struct item) {1, "pen", 5, 10};
```